# How can I calculate the minimum value of numbers that are found in a .txt file using the C programming language?

Tags: c

I am trying to scan a .txt file and calculate the minimum GPA, maximum GPA, and average GPA using some pointers in the C programming language. A sample of the .txt file is below, it contains a student number and a gpa, separated by a comma.

```
123, 5.6
321, 4.2
458, 1.2
64, 3.678
82, 1.2091
```

I have attached my code down below. I have figured out how to find the maximum and average GPAs, but I am having quite a bit of difficulty finding the minimum GPA.

```
void calcStats(FILE* inFile, double* avgGPAptr, double* maxGPAptr, double* minGPAptr){
    double sum = 0, GPA, line = 0;

    while(fscanf(inFile, "%*d %*c %lf", &GPA) == 1){
        sum = sum + GPA;
        line = line + 1;
 
        if(GPA < *minGPAptr){    /*This is the part of the code where I am running into a problem*/
            *minGPAptr = GPA;
        }
        if(GPA > *maxGPAptr){
            *maxGPAptr = GPA;
        }
    }

    *avgGPAptr = sum/line;

    printf("Average GPA: %.2lf \n", *avgGPAptr);
    printf("Minimum GPA: %.2lf \n", *minGPAptr);
    printf("Maximum GPA: %.2lf \n", *maxGPAptr);
}
```

The maximum and average GPA calculations work as expected, but the minimum always ends up equaling 0.

If you could help me out with this, that would be great.

Comment: Post how `calcStats()` is called.

Comment: If *minGPAptr is initialized to 0 then no GPA will be less than 0 right ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't show how this function is called, but presumably `*minGPAptr` has a value of 0 when the function is called.  So any positive value that is subsequently read in will be larger than that.

One way you can handle this is by ensuring `*minGPAptr` is set to a value larger than any valid value before you start reading anything.  Then the first value will be smaller than that and become the minimum.  You should do the same for `*maxGPAptr`, setting it smaller than any valid value to start.

```
 *minGPAptr = 999999;
 *maxGPAptr = -1;
 while(fscanf(inFile, "%*d %*c %lf", &GPA) == 1){
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I realized I needed to initialize it to something other than 0, but I honestly had no clue on what value to put in. I appreciate the help. I just set the value of *maxGPAptr to -0.1, as we can't have a negative GPA anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

With `calcStats()` notice that code nicely ignores any previous `*avgGPAptr` and simply sets `*avgGPAptr`.

```
void calcStats(FILE* inFile, double* avgGPAptr, double* maxGPAptr, double* minGPAptr){
  ... 
  *avgGPAptr = sum/line;
}
```

Yet `GPA < *minGPAptr` relies on the value of `*minGPAptr` prior to the `calcStats()` call.  This is certainly causing OP's trouble.

```
void calcStats(FILE* inFile, double* avgGPAptr, double* maxGPAptr, double* minGPAptr){
    ... 
    if(GPA < *minGPAptr){
```

---

Instead, simply set `GPA < *minGPAptr` at the start of `calcStats()` to extreme values.

```
#include <float.h>

void calcStats(FILE* inFile, double* avgGPAptr, double* maxGPAptr, double* minGPAptr){
  *maxGPAptr = -DBL_MAX;
  *minGPAptr = DBL_MAX;
  ...
    ... 
    if(GPA < *minGPAptr){
```